# How 'Select * into' works into background?

Tags: sql-server-2014

Today I came through the weird issue for which I need your help. Basically, I am copying a table(temp_a) into table (temp_b) using below query.

```
select * into temp_b  
from temp_a  
where cast(date_from as date)>='2010-01-01'  
and cast(date_from as date)<'2018-01-01'
```

Temp_a table Structure and sample data:
id int primary key,
name  varchar not null,
date_from datetime,
update_time getdate()

```
Temp_A  
ID           name         date_from         update_time  
-------------------------------------------------------
1            A            2010-01-01        2010-01-01
2            B            2011-02-02        2011-02-02
3            C            2012-02-02        2012-02-02
4            D            2013-09-09        2013-09-09
5            E            2014-08-06        2014-08-06
```

But above query results duplicate records in temp_b table.

```
Temp_B
ID           name         date_from         update_time
------------------------------------------------------- 
1            A            2010-01-01        2010-01-01
1            A            2010-01-01        2010-01-01
2            B            2011-02-02        2011-02-02
3            C            2012-02-02        2012-02-02
3            C            2012-02-02        2012-02-02
4            D            2013-09-09        2013-09-09
5            E            2014-08-06        2014-08-06
```

Can someone please elaborate what would be the reason for duplicate records in destination table when there is no duplicate in the source table.

**Or**

How "Select * into" works in the background?

Comment: Only plausible explanation: you had already run that query before on `temp_b`. Either that, or `temp_b` is not just a table but a `VIEW` with a messed up query behind it.

Comment: @Ext3h an error would be thrown if temp_b already existed. Ganesh have you dropped the table and had this behavior repeated? I don't see how this would work like this... if it truly is simply a table, at least not without a union all.